# Horn clause to Prolog

Tags: first-order-logic, prolog

At the needs of my HW at uni I need to transform some Horn clauses to Prolog but I cannot figure out how to do it. I found out some guides but they describe how to do it with only one fact. So can you give me a brief example on how to do it?

Eg John is beautiful and rich

we can transform it at: `not (Beautiful(John)) ^ not(Rich(John))` which is a Horn clause right? So how this can be translated it Prolog?

another example Everyone loves somebody.
Horn clause: $\forall X \exists Y Loves(X,Y)$ how can this be implemented in Prolog?

Thx in advance

Comment: Prolog is almost directly Horn clauses...

Comment: I suspect you might benefit from reviewing your understanding of Horn clauses.  You might look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A horn clause is a disjunction with at most one positive literal, e.g.

\begin{align}
\lnot X_1 \lor \lnot X_2 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot X_n \lor Y
\end{align}

The implication $X \rightarrow Y$ can be written as disjunction $\lnot X \lor Y$ (proof by truth table). If $X = \lnot X_1 \lor \lnot X_2 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot X_n $, then $\lnot X$ is equivalent to $X_1 \land X_2 \land \ldots \land X_n$ (De Morgan's law). Therefore, the above clause is logically equivalent to

\begin{align}
(X_1 \land X_2 \land \ldots X_n) \rightarrow Y
\end{align}

A Prolog program basically is a (large) list of horn clauses. A Prolog clause (called rule) is of the form
`head :- tail.`,
which in logic notation is $head \leftarrow tail$. Therfore, any horn clause

\begin{align}
\lnot X_1 \lor \lnot X_2 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot X_n \lor Y
\end{align}

is written in Prolog notation as `Y :- X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn.`

A horn clause containing no positive literal , e.g. $\lnot X_1 \lor \lnot X_2 \lor \ldots \lor \lnot X_n$ can be rewritten as $(X_1 \land X_2 \land \ldots X_n) \rightarrow \bot$, which is `:- X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn.` in Prolog notation.

Regarding your examples:

1. *"John is beautiful and rich"*, is a CNF, and each clause contains at most one positive literal, hence it can be written in Prolog as `beautiful(john).` and `rich(john).`
2. $\forall X \ \exists Y \ \operatorname{Loves}(X,Y)$

   That nested extential quantifier can be eleminated by [Skolemization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form), which is introducing a new function for the extential quantifier inside the universal quantifier: $\forall X \ \operatorname{Loves}(X,p(x))$, which in Prolog notation is `loves(X,p(X)).`