# Convert FOL clauses to PROLOG

Tags: first-order-logic, prolog

I am very new to PROLOG so it might be a very trivial question, but I absolutely have no idea how to solve it. There are 4 sentences I need to formulate into PROLOG code:

> - All hounds howl at night.
> - Anyone who has any cats will not have any mice.
> - Light sleepers do not have anything which howls at night.
> - John has either a cat or a hound.

I convert sentences to well-formed formula in first-order predicate calculus like that

```
- ∀x (HOUND(x) → HOWL(x))

- ∀x ∀y (HAVE(x,y) ∧ CAT (y) → ¬∃z (HAVE(x,z) ∧ MOUSE (z)))

- ∀x (Light_Sleeper(x) → ¬∃y (HAVE (x,y) ∧ HOWL(y)))

- ∃x (HAVE (John,x) ∧ (CAT(x) ∨ HOUND(x)))
```

Now I don't know how to write them in Prolog.
Also, how can I make query on them?

Comment: There are no trivial prolog questions, so don't despair!

Comment: Why do you think you *can* convert arbitrary first-order formulas into Prolog?

Comment: @DerekElkins  If I can't convert  the FOL into Prolog .. what would I do to  convert the previous English sentences  into Prololg?

Comment: Again, why do you think that's something you can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you can convert them to Horn clauses, you can convert them to Prolog.

If you can't convert them to Horn clauses, I don't think you can convert them to Prolog.

So, convert them to Horn clauses first, and then see the answer to this question:

[Horn clause to Prolog](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22682/horn-clause-to-prolog)